# Visual Studios Menu not showing build button

Tags: menu

Hi I'm trying to teach myself c++ but I can't even get the most important feature to work. The build/compile button won't show. Its grayed out. I only want to use visual studios because its what all the devs use in my friends company where I want to work. So, any way to get this thing working? This is Visual Studios 2013, I've tried the profile changing feature in attempt to fix it but it still shows up as grayed out and I can't use it. I have made no other changes since installing it.

Also to start my code I did file> new> file> C++ file

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio relies on projects, so you need for your source file to be part of a project - this would also hold all the configuration for compilation and linker settings, analogous to a *nix style Makefile.

To create a new project, Do **File** > **New** > **Project...** And choose a suitable template from under the Visual C++ section. Typically, if you're just starting out, and only want to work with the console, then you'll probably want to choose "Win32 Console Application" as the project type.